# How visible should I make the parameters in a function?

Tags: python, function, coding-style

Let's say we have a function that takes as parameters values from a dictionary. Should I include all individual parameters or just the whole dictionary as a parameter ?

Below is a simple example:

```
customer_orders = [{"ID": 1, "PRICE": 20, "QUANTITY": 2, "IN_STOCK": "YES"}, 
                   {....}]

# Way 1

def get_total(price, quantity):
    total = price * quantity
    return total

price = customer_orders[0]["PRICE"]
quantity = customer_orders[0]["QUANTITY"]
order_total = get_total(price, quantity)

# Way 2
def get_total(customer_order):
    price = customer_order["PRICE"]
    quantity = customer_order["QUANTITY"]
    total = price * quantity
    return total

order_total = get_total(customer_orders[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vote for `Way 2` as it hides more of the work in your function. This makes your main code cleaner and easier to understand. The function is more complex but if it is named well (as it is in this case) this makes it easier to understand.

+1 for noting this is a style question.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the question entirely by not using plain dictionaries here. Instead, use a class - a `namedtuple` fits well here, but subclass it so you can add `total` as a property:

```
from collections import namedtuple

ordertuple = namedtuple('Order', ['ID', 'PRICE', 'QUANTITY', 'IN_STOCK'])
class CustomerOrder(ordertuple):
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.PRICE * self.QUANTITY
```

The all-caps attribute names are ugly, but if they match the dictionary keys you already have, you can transform the list of dicts into a list of `namedtuples` like this:

```
customer_orders = [CustomerOrder(**order) for order in customer_orders]
```

Depending on how you get those dictionaries in the first place, you might be able to create namedtuples instead at that point, and use the normal lower-case convention for the attributes.

Comment: You can also use `namedtuple('Order', 'ID PRICE QUANTITY IN_STOCK')` which I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility, although I don't know if it's better:

```
# Way 3
def get_total(PRICE, QUANTITY, **customer_order):
    total = PRICE * QUANTITY
    return total

get_total(**customer_orders[0])
```